# VIM split line into multiple line based on delimiter

Tags: vim

In vim, is there an efficient way to split a line such as

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

into

```
a;
b;
c;
d;
e;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use command [`:substitute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute) (search and replace) in a line, replacing globally (all occurrences in the line) `,`  with `;\r` (end-of-line):

```
:s/, /;\r/g
```

There is no `,`  after the last `e` so there is no `;` after it. Append it manually.

*Upd* from @SergioAraujo from comments:

```
:s/, \|$/;\r/g
```

to search and replace either `,`  or the end of the line.

Comment: Append manually is less keystrokes but adding a normal command to the substitute is kind of more natural to me. `:s/, /\r/g|%norm A;`

Comment: I did something a little bit different `:%s/, \|$/;\r/g`  using alternatives with `\|`

Comment: @SergioAraujo Good! Let me steal it and add to my answer. :-)

Comment: [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)Of course, feel free to use it

Answer (score 1):

While more expensive in terms of keystrokes, the following method may be more intuitive and require a bit less thinking/planning, which is something to take into account when talking about efficiency:

```
f,
cW;<CR><Esc>
;.
;.
;.
A;<Esc>
```

Or, using `:help gn`:

```
/,<CR>
cgn;<CR><Esc>
.
.
.
A;<Esc>
```

Comment: The `/` solution is missing a `n` before the `.`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers no, it has `cW` instead of `cgn`, which I forgot to change after pasting. Thanks, fixed..